# Changing scrolling function between 2 divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this code to add some classes to a menu item when you scroll down to "yellow section"

```
var showing = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   var topofbox = ($('#yellow-section').position().top - ($('#yellow-section').position().top / 2)), //start height
       hH = $('#yellow-section').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();


   if (wS > (topofbox+hH-wH)){
    if(showing == false){
       $( ".position" ).fadeIn();
       $( ".position" ).addClass("animated rubberBand");
       $( ".c1" ).addClass("yellowcircle");
       $( ".c2" ).addClass("yellowoutline");
       $( ".c3" ).addClass("yellowoutline");
       $( ".c4" ).addClass("yellowoutline");
       $( ".c5" ).addClass("yellowoutline");
       $( ".c6" ).addClass("yellowoutline");
       showing = true;
}
   }
   else{
    if(showing == true){
    $( ".position" ).fadeOut();
    showing = false;
   }
}
});
```

And my HTML :

```
 <div class="position">
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 vcenter">
        <div class="circle c1"></div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 vcenter">
        <div class="circle c2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 vcenter">
        <div class="circle c3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 vcenter">
        <div class="circle c4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 vcenter">
        <div class="circle c5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 vcenter">
        <div class="circle c6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
```

There are several more sections further down which i would like to change the class when it hits, but i only seem to be able to do this when the position is before the yellow-section or after the yellow-section.

I would like to achieve a change of class every time the screen scrolls to a different div (red-section, green-section) - please can someone assist?

Comment: a bit of your html will help ;)

Comment: Done, sorry. I just want to do somethng when my page gets past certain Divs, it works on the yellow-section but im struggling to get an end point

Comment: I'm sorry, but without css I really can't help you. And I can't see your "yellowsection" in your code.